# Reposicionar o menu lateral para flutuante ao diminuir janela

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde. Estive pesquisando bastante no google, stackoverflow americano e aqui, mas não consegui achar o que precisava. Se achei algo parecido talvez não tenha identificado que poderia me servir.

Sou iniciante/estagiário nessa área e estou montando uma página html. Possuo um menu lateral e este menu é oculto ao diminuir a página para 750px e então é exibido um botão na header que deveria exibir este mesmo menu quando clicado e o fundo da página ficar meio cinza, como se estivesse desabilitado.

Comecei a fazer com uma dica que peguei em CSS, o menu lateral some ao diminuir a página, o ícone do menu aparece, mas a parte que falta é conseguir exibir o menu após clicar no ícone. Não entendi porque não está exibindo após clicado (checked). Li uma documentação de NAVBAR no site getbootstrap, mas não consegui aplicar ao meu código também.

Se alguém souber uma dica, agradeceria. Pode ser em CSS ou JS. Um desenvolvedor aqui da empresa disse que poderia usar ajax, jquery, bootstrap. Só não poderia usar angular. Obrigado.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http:/www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11 IE=10 IE=9 width=device-width initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1" name="viewport"
  />
  <title>Intranet</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="media/img/favicon.ico">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/sidebar.css">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/init.js"></script>

  <script>
    // var msg = "${msg}";
    // $(document).ready(function () {
    //   if (msg) {
    //     $('#modalMessage').modal().find('.modal-body p').text(msg);
    //   }
    // });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <a href="#" title="Suporte Tecnológico"></a>
          </div>
          <input class=".btnMenu" type="checkbox" id="bt_menu">
          <label for="bt_menu"> <i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main class="flex-fill">
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="dashside">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
          <h3>Olá, Usuário</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- <button class="btn-menu">
          <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
        </button> -->
        <div class="panel">
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:20px"></i> Aplicações</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:20px"></i> Tokens</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:20px"></i> Serviços</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="backgroundImage"></div>

      <div class="dashmain">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="panel">
              <h4>CADASTRO DA APLICAÇÃO</h4>
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="clientId">Sistema</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="systemId" aria-describedby="systemIdHelp" placeholder="Nome do Sistema" />
                  <small id="systemIdHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Preencha o nome do Sistema.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="clientId">Cliente</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientId" aria-describedby="clientIdHelp" placeholder="Nome do Cliente" />
                  <small id="clientIdHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Prencha o nome do Cliente.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="clientSecret">Chave Secreta</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientSecret" aria-describedby="clientSecretHelp" placeholder="Chave secreta do Cliente"
                  />
                  <small id="clientIdHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Preencha uma chave secreta</small>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 support">
          <strong>Suporte Tecnológico
            <br>3004 0000 (Capital e regiões
            <br>metropolitanas) ou 0800 000 0000
            <br>(Demais regiões)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 links">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" title="Segurança">Segurança</a> |
          <a href="#" title="Rede de Atendimento">Rede de Atendimento</a> |
          <a href="#" title="Ajuda">Ajuda</a> |
          <a href="#" title="Termos e Contratos">Termos e Contratos</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer style="position: relative;">
  </div>
  <div id="modalMessage" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Mensagem</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary orange" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script>



  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

E o CSS:

```
div .dashside .sidebar-header {
/* background-color: rgb(41, 111, 167); */
color: white;
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 14px;
}

div .dashside h3 {
    color: white;
}

div.dashside ul {
    padding: 0px !important;
}

div.dashside ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.dashside ul li {
    list-style: none;
    left: -10px;
}

div.dashside ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

div.dashside ul li a:hover {
    /* color: #007ad9; */
    background: rgb(212, 158, 82);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div.dashside ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

.dashside .sidebar-nav a {
    background: #007ad9;
    color: white;
    width: 105%;
}

/* .btn-menu {
    background-color: rgb(240, 165, 60);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    size: 80px;
} */

div .dashmain h4 {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(41, 111, 167);
}

div .form-group label {
    font-weight: 600;
}

div .form-group small {
    font-weight: 500;
}

div.dashmain {
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 700px;
}

div.dashside {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 100%;
    /* background-color: rgb(41, 111, 167); */
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(41, 111, 167), rgb(0, 79, 144));
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

div .dashmain .container-fluid {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 177, 68), rgb(255, 161, 29));
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

header .container-fluid {
    position: absolute;
}

header a {
    margin-left: 280px;
}

header .col {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(41, 111, 167), rgb(1, 78, 141));
    /* margin-bottom: 2px; */
}

div .btn-menu2 {
    background-color: rgb(240, 165, 60);
    color: white;
    display: none;
    float: right;
}

div .row {
    background: rgb(1, 78, 141);
}

label[for="bt_menu"] {
    background-color: rgb(255, 180, 40);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#bt_menu {
    display: none;
}

label[for="bt_menu"] {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    label[for="bt_menu"] {
        display: block;
    }
    .dashside {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: -100%;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .dashside ul li {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    div .dashmain {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        transition: 0.6s;
    }
    header a {
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    #bt_menu:checked~.dashside {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é o problema, mas tem um erro aqui na classe desta linha: `<input class=".btnMenu" type="checkbox" id="bt_menu">`... o ponto está incorreto, seria `class="btnMenu"`(sem o ponto).

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap vc está usando?

Answer (score 2):

Considerando:

> *- "mas a parte que falta é conseguir exibir o menu após clicar no ícone"*.

e:

> *- "poderia usar ajax, jquery, bootstrap"*.

Fiz o seguinte *script* com *jQuery* (mesma versão que você está usando):

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#bt_menu').on('change', function(){
      $('.dashside').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
      }, 500);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Lembre-se de:

1) Consertar o seu `input#bt_menu`:

```
<input class="btnMenu" type="checkbox" id="bt_menu">
```

2) Remover este bloco do seu *CSS*, já que, neste exemplo, estamos fazendo com *jQuery*:

```
#bt_menu:checked ~ .dashside {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

**Considerações finais**:

Foquei-me especificamente na sua pergunta resolvendo exclusivamente este problema. Tem formas melhores de criar uma solução para o seu projeto, o que acaba não sendo o objetivo desta resposta. Até por que daria uma gigantesca mão de obra rodar/reproduzir seu projeto por completo, considerando que não foram postados os arquivos deste. Veja:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/sidebar.css">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/init.js"></script>
```

Tome este *script* que lhe fiz apenas como um pequeno exemplo para criar uma solução melhor que resolva o problema do seu projeto como um todo.

Upei seu código no meu [GitHub/LipESprY/sopt-reposicionar-o-menu-lateral-para-flutuante-ao-diminuir-janela](https://github.com/lipespry/sopt-reposicionar-o-menu-lateral-para-flutuante-ao-diminuir-janela) e as alterações que citei estão visivelmente destacadas neste [commit](https://github.com/lipespry/sopt-reposicionar-o-menu-lateral-para-flutuante-ao-diminuir-janela/commit/8d4b0267a50f23ff1ba691b21308da4853c4be6d).

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma versão com jQuery, apenas para fazer um `toogleClass`. Assim quando vc clica no `btn` eu adiciono uma classe no `sidemenu` e ele entra na tela. Para fazer o efeito escurecido no fundo eu coloquei um `box-shadow` gigante que vai cobrir tudo que estiver abaixo. Para isso precise colocar z-index no `btn` do menu e no próprio `sidemenu`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Tinha um erro no seu código, vc tinha fechado o `<main>` no lugar errado, mas corrigi isso tb.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http:/www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11 IE=10 IE=9 width=device-width initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1" name="viewport"
  />
  <title>Intranet</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="media/img/favicon.ico">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/sidebar.css">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/init.js"></script>

  <script>
    // var msg = "${msg}";
    // $(document).ready(function () {
    //   if (msg) {
    //     $('#modalMessage').modal().find('.modal-body p').text(msg);
    //   }
    // });
  </script>
  <style>
  E o CSS:

div .dashside .sidebar-header {
/* background-color: rgb(41, 111, 167); */
color: white;
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 14px;
}

div .dashside h3 {
    color: white;
}

div.dashside ul {
    padding: 0px !important;
}

div.dashside ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.dashside ul li {
    list-style: none;
    left: -10px;
}

div.dashside ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

div.dashside ul li a:hover {
    /* color: #007ad9; */
    background: rgb(212, 158, 82);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div.dashside ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

.dashside .sidebar-nav a {
    background: #007ad9;
    color: white;
    width: 105%;
}

/* .btn-menu {
    background-color: rgb(240, 165, 60);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    size: 80px;
} */

div .dashmain h4 {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(41, 111, 167);
}

div .form-group label {
    font-weight: 600;
}

div .form-group small {
    font-weight: 500;
}

div.dashmain {
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 700px;
}

div.dashside {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 100%;
    /* background-color: rgb(41, 111, 167); */
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(41, 111, 167), rgb(0, 79, 144));
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

div .dashmain .container-fluid {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 177, 68), rgb(255, 161, 29));
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

header .container-fluid {
    position: absolute;
}

header a {
    margin-left: 280px;
}

header .col {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(41, 111, 167), rgb(1, 78, 141));
    /* margin-bottom: 2px; */
}

div .btn-menu2 {
    background-color: rgb(240, 165, 60);
    color: white;
    display: none;
    float: right;
}

div .row {
    background: rgb(1, 78, 141);
}

label[for="bt_menu"] {
    background-color: rgb(255, 180, 40);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#bt_menu {
    display: none;
}

label[for="bt_menu"] {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    label[for="bt_menu"] {
        display: block;
        z-index: 1001;
    }
    .dashside {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: -100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        
    }
    .dashside.ativo {
        margin-left: 0%;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 0px 0px 10000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) !important;
        

    }
    /* .dashside::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    } */
    .dashside ul li {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    div .dashmain {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        transition: 0.6s;
    }
    header a {
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    #bt_menu:checked~.dashside {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <a href="#" title="Suporte Tecnológico"></a>
          </div>
          <input class=".btnMenu" type="checkbox" id="bt_menu">
          <label for="bt_menu" id="menu"> <i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main class="flex-fill">
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="dashside">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
          <h3>Olá, Usuário</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- <button class="btn-menu">
          <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
        </button> -->
        <div class="panel">
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:20px"></i> Aplicações</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:20px"></i> Tokens</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:20px"></i> Serviços</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="backgroundImage"></div>

      <div class="dashmain">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="panel">
              <h4>CADASTRO DA APLICAÇÃO</h4>
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="clientId">Sistema</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="systemId" aria-describedby="systemIdHelp" placeholder="Nome do Sistema" />
                  <small id="systemIdHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Preencha o nome do Sistema.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="clientId">Cliente</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientId" aria-describedby="clientIdHelp" placeholder="Nome do Cliente" />
                  <small id="clientIdHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Prencha o nome do Cliente.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="clientSecret">Chave Secreta</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientSecret" aria-describedby="clientSecretHelp" placeholder="Chave secreta do Cliente"
                  />
                  <small id="clientIdHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Preencha uma chave secreta</small>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </main>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 support">
          <strong>Suporte Tecnológico
            <br>3004 0000 (Capital e regiões
            <br>metropolitanas) ou 0800 000 0000
            <br>(Demais regiões)</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 links">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" title="Segurança">Segurança</a> |
          <a href="#" title="Rede de Atendimento">Rede de Atendimento</a> |
          <a href="#" title="Ajuda">Ajuda</a> |
          <a href="#" title="Termos e Contratos">Termos e Contratos</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  
  <div id="modalMessage" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Mensagem</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary orange" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <script>
$('#menu').click(function() {
    $('.dashside').toggleClass("ativo");
});
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Olá, Hugo. Gostaria de agradecer a solução,funcionou perfeitamente.Ficou quase como eu queria,mas faltaram duas coisas (mais por minha parte por não ter dito).Ao clicar nesse botão,queria que o fundo, além de ficar meio cinza, que o usuário não pudesse clicar em nada. Os links e formulários estão "clicáveis".Outra coisa que queria era que o menu lateral sumisse não somente quando clicasse no botão menu,mas em qualquer lugar da página.Até achei soluções para isso, mas uma funcionam somente quando a página é carregada pequena e outra qdo a página está grande. Usei margin-left para isso.Obrigado

Comment: Faltou somente isso de funcionalidade para entregar. A parte de layout estou conseguindo arrumar. Outra coisa que queria saber é: Esse código parecia ser simples para quem tem experiência. Já fiz um curso de javascript e não me recordo dessa função. Há algum site que eu possa estudar mais sobre essas funcionalidades? Obrigado.

Comment: @LuizFelippeSerrano tem como fazer essas coisas que vc precisa sim! Mas te recomendo que abra uma Nova Pergunta, coloque seu código atualizado e descreve esses novos problemas que está enfrentando. Eu não vou poder ver isso agora pq tb vou ter que parar para estudar os métodos xD, eu não sou muito bom com JS ou jQuery, mas realmente não é algo difícil de resolver para quem sabe. Sobre os estudo eu recomendo que vc procure por tutoriais online, leias as perguntas antiga e bem pontuadas e veja como essas perguntas foram respondidas etc. Como falei abra uma nova pergunta que alguém vai te ajudar